# Sum of Dirac measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \delta_{x_k}$. I want to prove that if $\mu(B) = \infty$, then the following function
$$g_B(\mu) := \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{2^n} \mu(I_{n,j} \cap B) \wedge 1 = \infty,$$
where $a \wedge b = \min(a,b)$ and for $j\in \{1,...,2^n\}$ $I_{n,j} = ((j-1)2^{-n}, j2^{-n}]$. Of course $B \subseteq (0,1]$.

I know intuitively that it should be true because $\operatorname{diam} \hspace{0.5ex} I_{n,j} \rightarrow 0$ but can't prove it formally.

Comment: Note that $\mu(A)\wedge1=1$ if $A$ contains at least one $x_k$, and zero otherwise. So your sum just counts how many of the intersections contain some $x_k$. It follows that the result is false if all $x_j$ are the same. Did you want to add the condition that the $x_k$ are distinct?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yes, there are no multiplicities, the points are distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Fix some finite positive $m$. Note that when $n$ is large enough, none of the intervals $I_{n,j}$ can contain more than one of the points $x_{1},\ldots,x_{m}$, but each of those points is contained in one of the intervals. Conclude that $g_B(\mu)\ge m$. (I am assuming here without loss of generality that all $x_k\in(0,1]$.)